# Laravel 5.8 | Redirect to previous URL after login/register/reset password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

i have in my LoginController function:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
        if ($user->is_admin == true) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return redirect('/');
}
```

and in RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{      
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()  && Auth::user()->is_admin == true) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
}
```

I tried too use in both places:

```
return redirect()->intended();
and
return redirect()->back();
```

but every time it brings me under

```
localhost/
```

Focusing on the user part, I'm trying to do a login redirect to the previous URL. Could someone please help me to correct this redirect?

Thank you

Comment: send to current url within the form and redirect with `$request->post('redirect_url', '/home')`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#included-authenticating):

> If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a
> redirectTo method instead of a redirectTo property

So instead of `protected $redirectTo = '/';`

Try

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return url()->previous();
}
```

Comment: and my function should return redirect()->back() instead of redirect('/');?

Comment: if you want it to return from where it came, yes. `redirect('/')` is a redirect to the homepage.

Comment: sorry, `redirect()->back()` won't work here. I've edited my answer

Comment: Okey I changed to return url()->previous(); but it redirect me to blank page with "http://domain.example/login" text on the left. So it return wrong URL. I need to back one more step.

Answer (score 0):

After I changed this

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

to this

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return redirect()->back();
}
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
    if ($user->is_admin == true) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

i got error:
The localhost page caused too many redirects.